# How to resolve error using Where Clause on Graph edge data?

Tags: vora

I have a simple Graph and can run the following query which brings back the NAME property of "Customer" nodes along with the NODETYPE property of edges named "SIMILAR_TO":

```
SELECT NAME, SIMILAR_TO.NODETYPE FROM CUSTOMER USING GRAPH 
MY_CUSTOMER_PROSPECT_GRAPH;
```

This yields expected tabular data. Now I want to filter the edges to grab only those of a certain NODETYPE by running this SQL:

```
SELECT NAME, SIMILAR_TO.NODETYPE FROM CUSTOMER USING GRAPH 
MY_CUSTOMER_PROSPECT_GRAPH
where SIMILAR_TO.NODETYPE = 'SIM';
```

But this fails with the following error:

```
could not handle api call, failure reason : execution of scheduler plan 
failed: found problem category: exception for node id 8 - error code is 58 
error msg: [ Graph Semantics ] Query parse error (code 58): unexpected 
expression: (NODE_5.SIMILAR_TO.NODETYPE = 'SIM');
```

Similarly, you cannot use {Edge}.NODEID in the where clause either (same error). This appears to be new to version 2.1 (2.1.35 is the exact version I'm running) as I am trying to migrate existing graph models that ran correctly in previous versions. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: 2.1.35 is not an officially released build. 2.1.43 was the GA version and current latest publicly available version is 2.1.60. Could you try again with a current official version?

Comment: Thank you. I will try again if/when I get my hands on a later version. FYI, the current Developer Edition of SAP Data Hub also runs with Vora version 2.1.35 (as of March 26, 2018).